# Custom Project Directory from Android New Project Wizard in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, ide-customization

I would like to know how to create a customized directory structure template that will be created each time I start a new project.  Rather than having to create files, and folders over and over, is there a way to just have the New Project Wizard create them by default in Eclipse?  I know you can customize the content of files by modifying the template.  I am interested in creating new folders and perhaps new customized files in those folders.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do this in Eclipse, but one thing that comes to mind is to create a sort of template project setup the way you want it and then just copy it. I don't know if you are working with plugin projects, if you copy a plugin project, make sure you fix the manifest to change the name of the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Francis.  That's basically what I do currently, except my process is a little more manual.  I was hoping to skip the manual part :)